# How to remove imageview from layout and add textview before converting the layout into image

Tags: android-linearlayout, android-imageview, android-view

Im developing one app, In that app, Im sharing image in social networks(Converting the layout into image) so my question is in my layout am having share icon, so i want remove that share icon and add textview to that layout before converting into image. can anyone give solution for my question. Thanks in advance

```
    final View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
 itemView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    itemView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
           View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    itemView.layout(0, 0, 300, 400);
    itemView.buildDrawingCache(true);

  holder.share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             // Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mView.getWidth(), mView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(itemView.getWidth(),itemView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            itemView.draw(canvas);

            Uri bmpUri = null;

            try {
                // output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/path/to/file.png");
                File file =  new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
                file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);



                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                out.close();

                 bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, SplashScreen.newstitleArray.get(SplashScreen.myCustomPosition));
            sendIntent.setType("image/*");
            context1.startActivity(sendIntent);
        }
    });
```